# How to aggregate all assertion in testunit?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, testunit

I am new into watir and I am using testunit for assertion.
My script looks like this:
Script1 -- has a test method which calls Script2
Script2 -- does all the work and validation. This has all assertion

When i run my test case I have to run Script1, it runs successfully but result shows 1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips.

Here is my code:

This is in my first file

```
require_relative 'RubyDriver'
require 'test/unit'
class RubyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
def test_method
    driver = RubyDriver.new("/home/pratik/study/UIAutomation/WatirScript.xlsx")
    driver.call_driver
end
   end
```

And this is part of anotner file

```
require_relative 'ExcelReader'
require_relative 'RubyUtility'
require "watir-webdriver"
require 'test/unit'

class RubyDriver < Test::Unit::TestCase
def take_action
value_property = @rubyutil.get_property("#{value}")
if value_property
    value_prop = value_property.first.strip
    value_value = value_property.last.strip
end

case "#{@rubyutil.get_string_upcase("#{keyword}")}"

when "VERIFY"
    puts "verifying"
    puts value_prop
    puts value_value
    object.wait_until_present
    object.flash    
    if value_prop == "text"
        assert_equal(object.text, value_value,"Text does not match")
        # puts object.text.should == value_value
    elsif value_prop == "exist"
        value_boolean = value_value == "true" ? true : false
        assert_equal(object.exists?,value_boolean,"Object does not exist")
        # puts object.exists?.should == value_value
    end
```

Everything is working fine except report which shows as

```
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips.
```

Where is my number of assertions.

Any help please.

Comment: There are likely a lot of reasons why it is not working. If you share your code it would help us give more concrete answers.

Comment: Have edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your assertions within an instance of another class. If I recall correctly, assert increments the assertion count within its class instance. Therefore your assertion count is being incremented in your RubyDriver instance rather than the RubyTest instance. As a result, you get no assertions reported.

You need to do the assertions within the actual test case (ie `test_method` of RubyTest) that is being run by test/unit.

As an example, you could make RubyDriver include your driving logic and logic for retrieving values to test. RubyTest would then call RubyDriver to setup/get values and include your test logic.

```
class RubyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_method
    # Do some setup using RubyDriver instance
    driver = RubyDriver.new("/home/pratik/study/UIAutomation/WatirScript.xlsx")
    driver.call_driver

    # Use RubyDriver to get some value you want to test
    some_value_to_test = driver.get_value_to_test

    # Do the assertion of the value within RubyTest
    assert_equal(true, some_value_to_test, "Object does not exist")
  end
end
```

An alternative solution might be to pass the test case (RubyTest) to RubyDriver. Then have RubyDriver call the assertion methods using the RubyTest instance.

Here is a simplified working example where you can see that your assertion count is correctly updated. Note that the RubyTest instance is passed to RubyDriver and stored in the @testcase variable. All assertions are then run with the context of the @testcase - eg `@testcase.assert(false)`, which ensures that the original test cases' assertion counts are updated.

```
require 'test/unit'

class RubyDriver < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def initialize(file, testcase)
        @testcase = testcase
        super(file)     
    end

    def action
        @testcase.assert(false)
    end

end

class RubyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_method
        driver = RubyDriver.new("/home/pratik/study/UIAutomation/WatirScript.xlsx", self)
        driver.action
    end
end
```

I left the RubyDriver as a sub-class of Test::Unit::TestCase, though it seems a bit odd unless you also have actual tests in the RubyDriver.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in my case. My framework is written in such a way that my test method has to just call a method and then all execution/validation happens there

Comment: I added an alternative approach that requires minimal changes. Maybe that will be more acceptable for your framework.